# why Google Calendar all day events return start date as today with php

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am using Google calendar api V3 with PHP and am trying to get event's summary, description and start date.  My issue is with the last element: Start date.  When events in the calendar are set as "All day" events, the response from the following code gives me today's date and the exact time when the query was made:

```
echo "<div id=Activite class=titre>", $event->getSummary(), "</div>\n";

$event_date = (new DateTime($event->getStart()->getDateTime()))->format('d/m/Y H:i');
echo "<div class=date_start><span style=color:yellow;>Start: </span>", $event_date, "</div>\n";
```

Here is an example of what is returned:

```
prise de photos des élèves
Start: 22/11/2014 18:30
```

Reading the same output from the "Google APIs Explorer", I get:

```
start": {
"date": "2013-09-13"
```

Which is nothing like what I am getting in my case.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't used the API, but you should start with inspecting your data. For example, what does `var_dump($event->getStart()->getDateTime());` give you? My best guess is that DateTime cannot parse that string. Depending on your result, you can create the date from a string with a different format like: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', $event->getStart()->getDateTime());
echo $date->format('d/m/Y H:i');`

Comment: Very interesting but now, this is very puzzling.  Your great advice is telling me, as I tried the var_dump function, that this returns a NULL answer.  I find it very interesting because for posts that are not an all day event, the var_dump function returns the correct info.  But not for all day events.  If only I understood what is missing here.  On answers that are not all day events, I get a ver_dump like: string(25) "2013-09-17T15:30:00-04:00" .  What does string(25) mean?

Comment: string(25) is just var_dump telling you the type of the data "2013-09-17T15:30:00-04:00"  is a string with 25 chars. Running new DateTime on null gives you todays date, hence your results. What confuses DateTime is the "15:30:00-04:00". It cannot handle start AND end time, so you have to parse it yourself. You could just cut the string after the last dash to get the start time I guess.

Comment: Understood.  But what gets me is the fact that as Google uses the getStart function in their API, it doesn't work all the time.  Case in point, when an all day event is used, this function is NULL.  Where is the logic?  But thank you for your insights ippi.

Comment: Try `$event->getStart()->getDate()` for allday events. The logic is that all-day events doesn't have specific times. How would you decide what times an all-day event is? Do you set it to 00:00:00 and just hope people won't use that? Instead they use a separate field for dates. Date is not the same as DateTime, so having two fields for "almost" the same thing might seems confusing but it is probably the most logical solution there is.

Answer (score 5):

Well, here goes for the answer.  After great advise by "ippi", I got to understand that Google uses 2 different variables for an event: start... "Date" / "DateTime".  The code that worked for me is this work around that enabled the code to recognize if it was dealing with an all day event or not:

```
if (($event->getStart()->getDate())!= NULL) {
    $event_date = (new DateTime($event->getStart()->getDate()))->format('d/m/Y');
} else {
    $event_date = (new DateTime($event->getStart()->getDateTime()))->format('d/m/Y H:i');
}
```

Comment: in json it's start.date and start.dateTime (the capital T matters) as per https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert