# Problems retrieving date using Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to retrieve an event on a particular date using PHP and the Google Calendar API but I'm having issues getting events on the correct date. For example, I can see the event in the calendar but it's not being retrieved using the API, or there's nothing in the calendar and it's getting the event from the day before.

After researching and experimenting I thought it might be an issue with timezones but I can't see anything wrong in my code. It might be worth mentioning that all events in the calendar are all day events.

I'd really appreciate any help you can offer. (I'm a newbie coder and it's my first question so please let me know if I've missed anything!)

```
$eventdate = "26-08-2018";

 require_once "google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php";
      putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=MY_CREDENTIALS");
      $scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';

      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
      $client->setScopes($scope);
      $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

      $googleeventdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($eventdate));

      $optParams = array(
        "timeZone" => "Europe/London",
        "timeMin" => $googleeventdate . "T00:00:00Z",
        "timeMax" => $googleeventdate . "T23:59:59Z"
      );

      $events = $service->events->listEvents($googlecal, $optParams);

      foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {    
        echo "Events in Calendar: " . $event->summary;
      }
```

Comment: I suggest you use the Google Calendar V3. Then use the [`get`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) method to retrieve the events. Based from this [thread](https://github.com/ryancramerdesign/MarkupLoadGCal/issues/5), Google dropped the support for v2 on November 17, 2014. Check this [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php) using Google Calendar API.

Comment: Sorry, I may actually be using V3. I'm using the latest release from [link](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases) and sample code from [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). The get method seems to allow me to get a specific event using the event id but not by a specific date, which is why I'm using the list method.

Comment: In the end I took a slightly different approach. I retrieved all events over an extended time period and used php to check if my specific date fell within that time period. It was also useful to know that Google uses both getDate and getDateTime as summarised [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084674/why-google-calendar-all-day-events-return-start-date-as-today-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to set the time min and time max

```
// $eventdate = "26-08-2018";
$timeMin = date("c", strtotime( $eventdate) ); // gives 2018-08-26T00:00:00-04:00
$timeMax = date("c", strtotime( $eventdate.' +1 days') ); // gives 2018-08-27T00:00:00-04:00
```

You can test it [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)